# Crash on pre-launch of goolgle play store

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-play

Crash status google play pre-launch report on

```
Android Version
Android 8.1
Native Platform
armeabi-v7a
```

fine with other devices

is see the video and check the crash logs its not related to my app. whan app start the **chrome app was crashed**

here is the crash log and video

```
Issue: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Array resource ID #0x7f03000e


FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0, PID: 10331
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Array resource ID #0x7f03000e
    at android.content.res.Resources.obtainTypedArray(Resources.java:618)
    at android.content.res.Resources.preloadFonts(Resources.java:380)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5769)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.WebViewZygoteInit.main(WebViewZygoteInit.java:146)
```

[image]

Comment: We also have this problem, every time with the same device: Pixel 2, Android 8.1

Comment: It seems, that this is fixed by Google now.

Answer (score -1):

I just remove the downloadable font meta tag from manifest

```
  <meta-data
    android:name="preloaded_fonts"
    android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
```

my problem solved.

Comment: Does this make sense? Then the preloaded fonts will not work, or?

Comment: yes preloaded fonts will not work. Its a bug from google. To clear the prelaunch report u have no other options. If u find any solution then tell me I will mention that here. thanks.